# Got Server Error 500 Internal Server Error in AWS lightsail plesk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, plesk

I got `Server Error 500 Internal Server Error` this error when I add 3 lines of code in the .hraccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
php_value session.cookie_httponly 1
php_value session.cookie_secure 1
```

if I remove these three lines of code I code `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` this type of error.
I didn't find out the solution. Code is written is php

Answer (score 0):

The error 500 is caused by a disallowed "FollowSymLinks". This is the Plesk default setting in the Apache & Nginx settings "Restrict the ability to follow symbolic links" in order to prevent symlinks in an account by which content outside the subscription of that user could be accessed.

Instead of "+FollowSymLinks" use "+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" in your .htaccess file and you'll get the expected, working result.